# How does LinkedIn's OAuth2 support really works for REST API?

Tags: rest, oauth, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I am trying to use OAuth2 with LinkedIn, following the [official documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2). The answers I got from are inconsistent, or rather does not exhibit any consistent behaviour. [This SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28094926/linkedin-oauth2-unable-to-verify-access-token) question helped me somewhat: After switching to use `oauth2_access_token` query parameter I managed to be able to query information about the user.

However, each time I request a new access token and try to use it from my server I got the dreaded `Unable to verify access token` error. When I try to use the access token manually with a plain `curl`, it fails with same error **unless** I navigate to my LinkedIn page.

Can someone explains what's the correct workflow and parameters as LinkedIn's own documentation appears to be flawed? A server-side code example would be great...

Comment: How are you getting new access tokens? Through steps 1-3, or step 5?

Comment: I am doing 1-3 then it fails at 4.