# LinkedIn, 401, Unable to verify access token

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I used [this guide](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2) to built a showcase - sign in with LinkedIn into a specific site.
Everything worked **perfectly** until I demonstarted it in front of a wide audience and it broke down :-( It was a great FAIL and I want to know why. Here is what I do:

1.On the sign in page the user may click a `Sign in with LinkedIn` button and is redirected to similar link:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?redirect_uri=[my_callback]&client_id=[my_client_id]&response_type=code&state=[securely_random]&scope=r_basicprofile%20r_emailaddress
```

2.The user allows the application and is sent back to `my_callback`

3.In `my_callback` I make a POST to `https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken` in order to obtain an access token. I use the code sent by LinkedIn, correct client ID and secret. Everything is OK, e.g the response might be:

```
{
    "access_token": [access_token],
    "expires_in": 5184000
}
```

4.I make *authenticated requests* to fetch the profile data from endpoint `https://www.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(firstName,lastName,email_address)`

Headers:

```
x-li-format: json       
Authorization: Bearer [access_token]
```

I started to get an error 401 occasionally, e.g.:

```
{
  "errorCode": 0,
  "message": "Unable to verify access token",
  "requestId": "YX21AN6NZG",
  "status": 401,
  "timestamp": 1483732371224
}
```

It seems that some of the requests randomly passed nevertheless...

Additional details:

- The [user](https://www.linkedin.com/in/lachezar-balev-a151626) is logged in LinkedIn
- The user is administrator for the LinkedIn application
- I have checked the limitations (throttle limits) at in the application. Available at `https://www.linkedin.com/developer/apps`. Everything which can be seen is green.
- I have tried all advices and hacks from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28094926/linkedin-oauth2-unable-to-verify-access-token)
- My app is not live

I'm puzzled!

*Question:* Any obvious mistake?

*Question:* Is there any hidden throttle limits (or security instruments) for the limitation of the number of access tokens for specific user/app combination? (I'm always using the same user and I tested pretty aggressively before the big FAIL)

**UPDATE:** In the next two days the Sign in started working smoothly again as described above. No 401-s anymore... :-X I've made no changes to the code base. So is this some kind of throttle limit or just LI was in a bad mood on Friday?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone is curious I got an answer to my problem from LI support:

*Unfortunately, we really can't assist with API issues and 3rd party apps. My guess is that there was a hiccup on Friday and you were the victim of bad timing.*

I accept the explanation that I was a victim so this answers my question...

Comment: you're easy to be convinced :D

Comment: I have this same issue. As the hiccup not been resolved yet :D

Answer (score 0):

I have an access-token that worked to get data through the API, however now it has stopped working. I've carefully read LinkedIn's documentation: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2 and have come up with why this can happen.

*The docs state, that the user's session is linked with the access-token. Therefore, logging out of the session means the access-token is invalidated. This makes sense because it's exactly what I see happening.*

The oauth2 expired-at is just a timestamp of the ultimate time this access-token will be valid. But it can be invalidated at any moment apparently.

Other oauth2 implementations show features for refreshing the access-token, Linkedin does not provide such feature. Therefore a user has to refresh it manually every time. Not sure if this is by design or they haven't got around to it yet. Overall their API feels pretty out-dated.